# Is it possible for GWT to create client to server connection without my knowledge?

Tags: java, gwt, client, vaadin

Is it possible for GWT to create client to server connection without my knowledge? I know I can explicitly create an RPC connection, but is it possible in any case that GWT would generate some server side that client will require to work without my knowledge? I could not find any info about this. From my experience I have never noticed such a behavior. [At GWT documentation all I have found is](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/gettingstarted#compile):

> Congratulations! You've created your first web application using Google Web Toolkit. Since you've compiled the project, you're now running pure JavaScript and HTML that works in IE, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Opera. You could now deploy your application to production by serving the HTML and JavaScript files in your MyWebApp/war/ directory from your web servers.

However this does not guarantee that this kind of connection will not be created under some condition.

As far as I know Vaadin does create such connections for almost everything.

If anyone got any info where it states that GWT wont create any client<->server connection with some magic, I'll appreciate that.

Comment: I've always preferred to have the control of JavaScript.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not aware of any such statement (besides the source code itself, of course), but I can guarantee you (as a member of the GWT Steering Committee) that GWT won't talk to any server without an explicit action on your part (in your code).

Comment: Thanks a lot :). I would vote up, however I can't do that yet :/ :)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK GWT won't talk to the server without any user action.

You can use `GWT.runAsync();` to load contents later which are actually not required during initial loading. But then this is also an user action.